# String value with an apostrophe in a PHP variable email address, mysql select

Tags: php, mysql, email, variables, escaping

I have an email address mike.o'malley@stack.com stored in a posted variable and I want a select statement in mysql to validate the existance of the email address and retrieve a password from my table. 
My query gets stuck at the apostophe when it trys to execute. eg "SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName = '$email'";

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to quote the value.
In fact, you should use it every time you insert a value in a query, if you dont, you are not only open to errors, also to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).

You should use it like this:

```
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $email = stripslashes($email);
}
$quoted_email = mysql_real_escape_string($email, $db_connection);
$query = "SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName='".$quoted_email."'";
```

Edit:
If PHP has magic quotes on, all superglobals values ( values in $_GET, $_POST, ... ) are quoted with [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) which sucks. You should consider turning it off.

Comment: I tried it and get this when echoing my query, without result (naturally)
SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName = 'mike.o\\\'malley@stack.com'

Comment: I'm thinking you have magic quotes on. Gonna do an edit on that now.

Comment: ufortunately the same result as above :)

Comment: Yes, you should, it's a deprecated feature and it makes you do everything twice. It's strange it doesnt work.

Comment: I'm getting this now SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName = 'mike.o\'malley@stack.com'. I checked the database and the email address is correctly stored. I think it's the apostrophe... somehow

Comment: That query seems valid. I just tested retrieving a value with an apostrophe in it with that quoting and it worked. You should check if mysql throws any errors with mysql_error ( http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php )

Comment: Thanks for trying - I'll keep battling here to see if I can see it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), for example:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
```

Note this should be done regardless when using variable strings in unprepared SQL to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Using it but get this SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName = 'mike.o\'malley@stack.com'

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping $email in PHP's mysql_real_escape_string?  Sanitizing all your user generated input is a good idea..

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

**EDIT:**

Mike "\" is the MySQL escape character. Here is the [MySQL 5.0's documentation on strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html).

mysql_real_escape_string correctly escapes the email address as 'mike.o\'malley@stack.com'.  Here is a full example:

```
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'simeon', 'password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $link);

$email = "mike.o'malley@stack.com";
// Query
$query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'";

$result = mysql_query($query);   

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'email: '.$row['email']."\n";  // email: mike.o'malley@stack.com
}
```

Comment: Using it but get this SELECT pwd FROM tbl_users WHERE userName = 'mike.o\'malley@stack.com'

Comment: Michael, as Juan pointed out, please make sure magic quotes are turned off. Above, I've edited my post with a more detailed explanation. Hope this helps.